# Create a set of slices from a numpy array, for parallelization

Tags: numpy, parallel-processing, slice

I have a numpy array like `ids = ([0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,5,5,5])` and some other numpy arrays (say `a` and `b`) of the same length. I want to carry out some independent operations using slices of these arrays, with the slices defined as indexes that share the same (contiguous) set of ids. I.e. I want to define a set of slices like

```
slice_0 = 0:3
slice_1 = 3:5
slice_2 = 5:9
...
```

so that I can call a function `f(a[slice_n],b[slice_n])` for each n in parallel. How do I construct the slices in numpy? If it helps, in R I would do it with something like `tapply`.

Comment: Don't think creating slices would be a good idea when trying to use vectorization with NumPy, because essentially you would be running the method(s) sequentially. If you could specify the operation that you would to like use, there might be a better solution.

Comment: Is this a syntax question? Creating a slice for later use there are essentially two ways. Using `slice` objects or tuples of `slice` objects for multidimensional slicing (and `Ellipsis` for '...') or using `np.s_`.

Comment: @Divakar it's the function f(x) that takes time. I imagine the slicing would be quick.

Comment: @PaulPanzer it's a question of how to create slices that cover contiguous runs of the same number in a numpy int array

Comment: @user2667066 And that would happen because those apply functions aren't working in parallel on the sliced data, at least the NumPy based apply funcs.

Comment: what kind of f function will you apply ? in some cases it will be simple.

Comment: If the slices differ in length, they can't be used 'in parallel'

Comment: Are you sure you need slices here? You could use boolean masks, and then you don't even have to care if they're contiguous - `slice_0 = ids == 0`, etc

Comment: Just as an aside, you didn't sort all your data by `ids` just before this step did you?  Because becasue that would be a huge waste of time when you could just use boolean masks or `np.where` on unsorted data.

Comment: @DanielForsman no, the data come already sorted. But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get your split points:

```
spl=np.r_[0, np.where(np.nonzero(np.diff(ids)))[0] + 1, ids.size]
```

then a list of slices

```
slices=[slice(i,j) for i,j in zip(spl[:-1].flat, spl[1:].flat)]
```

or split your other arrays

```
a_spl=np.split(a,spl[1:-1])
```

EDIT: since `idx` is sorted and in order, you can either do `unique` above or do a boolean slicing (if you have the memory)

```
slices = list(np.unique(ids)[:,None] == ids[None,:])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, perhaps you intended

```
slice_0 = 0:3
slice_1 = 3:5
slice_2 = 5:9
slice_3 = 9:10
slice_4 = 10:13
```

If this is the case, you can use NumPy's [unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
_, idx, count = numpy.unique(ids, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
```

The lower limit of the slices is `idx`, the upper limit is `idx + count`.

Comment: Yes, typo, sorry. Will correct in the original question. I means 0:3, 3:5, etc.

Comment: Given that the ids are already sorted and in order, is there something more efficient than numpy.unique? What's used in bumpy for e.g. run length encoding?

Comment: You didn't specify that they are sorted and in order :)  In that case `unique` is actually probably better than the `diff` solutions below

Comment: If your point is to parallelize `f`, which is the slow part of the computation, I doubt that using `unique` on a sorted list will lead to a noticeable loss of efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that :

```
In [12]: arrays=vstack((a,b))  

In [13]: arrays
Out[13]: 
array([[4, 1, 4, 2, 5, 7, 1, 5, 9],
       [8, 1, 1, 1, 9, 3, 0, 3, 1]])

In [14]: subarrays=np.split(arrays,[3,5],axis=1)

In [15]: subarrays
Out[15]: 
[array([[4, 1, 4],
        [8, 1, 1]]), 
 array([[2, 5],
        [1, 9]]), 
 array([[7, 1, 5, 9],
        [3, 0, 3, 1]])]

In [16]: [multiply(a,b) for (a,b) in subarrays]
Out[16]: [array([32,  1,  4]), array([ 2, 45]), array([21,  0, 15,  9])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chop up an array into chunks along an axis the simplest way is `np.split`:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> split_points = (2,5,7)
>>> np.split(a, split_points)
[array([0, 1]), array([2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6]), array([7, 8, 9])]
```

If you want even splitting you can use `np.arange` for `split_points`.

To create split points from an id array use `split_points = np.where(np.diff(ids))[0] + 1`

If your id array is sorted and you also have the ids without repeats then `split_points = np.searchsorted(ids, ids_wor)[1:]` might be faster.